# LateInitializationError SharedPreferences - Problemas al inicializar

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Estoy intentando hacer un singleton de sharedpreferences, pero me da fallo de no inicializado.

**(LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.))**.

No se que puede estar fallando. Supongo que podría ser por el **late** de **SharedPreferences.dart**, o ¿le falta en algún lugar definir la inicialización?

[image]

**Personaje_home.dart**

```
class PersonajeHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonajeHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PersonajeHomePage> createState() => _PersonajeHomePageState();
}

class _PersonajeHomePageState extends State<PersonajeHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var estiloTexto = EstiloTextos();
    final proPersonaje = Provider.of<PersonajeProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(proPersonaje.leerLvLPersonaje.toString()),                 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SharedPreferences.dart**

```
class SharedPrefsPersonaje {
  static final SharedPrefsPersonaje _instancia = SharedPrefsPersonaje._internal();

  factory SharedPrefsPersonaje() {
    return _instancia;
  }
  SharedPrefsPersonaje._internal();

  late SharedPreferences prefs;
  initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  int get readExpPersonaje {
    return prefs.getInt("experiencia_personaje") ?? 0;
  }

  set saveExpPersonaje(int value) {
    prefs.setInt("experiencia_personaje", value);
  }

  int get readLvLPersonaje {
    return prefs.getInt("nivel_personaje") ?? 0;
  }

  set saveLvLPersonaje(int value) {
    prefs.setInt("nivel_personaje", value);
  }

  void eliminar() {
    prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  inicializamosCargaDatos();
  runApp(AppState());
}

class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        //Cargamos datos del JSON, servidor
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => PersonajeProvider(),
          lazy: false,
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "My APP",
      initialRoute: "/",
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: "/",
          page: () => const PersonajeHomePage(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Future<void> inicializamosCargaDatos() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();
  await prefs.initPrefs();

}
```

**Provider_personajes.dart**

```
 class PersonajeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();

  int xpPersonaje = 0;
  int lvlPersonaje = 0;

  get leerXPPersonaje {
    if (prefs.readExpPersonaje != 0) {
      return xpPersonaje = prefs.readExpPersonaje;
    }
    return xpPersonaje;
  }

  set guardarXPPersonaje(int xp) {
    xpPersonaje = xp + xpPersonaje;
    prefs.saveExpPersonaje = xpPersonaje;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get leerLvLPersonaje {
    if (prefs.readLvLPersonaje != 0) {
      return lvlPersonaje = prefs.readLvLPersonaje;
    }
    return lvlPersonaje;
  }

  set guardarLvLPersonaje(int lvl) {
    lvlPersonaje = lvl + lvlPersonaje;
    prefs.saveLvLPersonaje = lvlPersonaje;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void borrarDatos() {
    prefs.eliminar();
  }
}
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar esta línea final "prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje(); " por esta "SharedPrefsPersonaje prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();"

Answer (score 1):

donde vas a utilizar shared preferences, debes inicializarlo, no veo que lo inicializas en ningun lado.

Tu codigo

```
class PersonajeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();
```

Asi deberia quedar

```
class PersonajeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final prefs = SharedPrefsPersonaje();
  prefs.initPrefs();
```

Eso deberia solucionar tu problema.

O lo puedes llamar desde tu main

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final prefs = PreferenciasUsuario();
  await prefs.initPrefs();
```